# How to slice excel values based on row values

Tags: python, excel, xlrd

Actually i am reading an Excel sheet using python i know how to slice the rows based on no's,but what i want is to slice row values based on row values...
For example:

```
       col1  col2  col3
      ---------------
row1 | sss   2     3
row2 | ppp   4     5
row3 | vvv   6     7
```

I need to slice row but using row values like slice(col0,sss,vvv) like this i want.so that if any row order changes also i can access that row values based on name.

I dont need like this slice(0,4,6)...pls help me thanks in advance

Comment: Did you mean (2, 4, 6) not (0, 4, 6)?

Comment: i know how to slice using sheet.col_slice(colno,rowx,rowy) or sheet.row_slice(.....) but i want  to know the index of row from the row values ,like index(row1) from its values "sss" or "2" or "3" like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> so that if any row order changes also i can access that row values
>   based on name.

Based on that fragment and the diagram, you possibly want something like this (untested):

```
rd = {}
for rowx in xrange(1, sheet.nrows):
    cell = sheet.cell(rowx, 0)
    if cell.ctype != xlrd.XL_CELL_TEXT: continue
    cv = cell.value.strip()
    if not cv: continue
    if cv in rd:
        complain_about_duplicate_row_names()
    rd[cv] = sheet.row_values(rowx)
```

Comment: actually its printng all the values. What i want can i find the row index(row number) based on that corresponding row values. From the eg which i given the eg in that itself can u say how to find index of "row1" by using its values like "sss" or "2" or "3".